# Plugging MVC5 into an OWIN/Katana Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I read in article that web api 2 can be easlity be integrated in Owin pipeline.

- http://johnatten.com/2015/01/11/asp-net-web-api-2-2-create-a-self-hosted-owin-based-web-api-from-scratch/

// Owin code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var webApiConfiguration = ConfigureWebApi();

        // Use the extension method provided by the WebApi.Owin library:
        app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
    }


    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        return config;
    }
}
```

I've read a lot articles about OWIN specification, but I'm still a little confused, please help me to clarify the questions:

**Q:**

1. Is it possible to ingtegrate asp.net mvc5 to Owin pipeline in the
   same way as Web Api?
2. Or it is not possible due to tight binding to system.web assymbly?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thx for your attention! Please give examples or links to resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately it's not possible to run ASP.Net MVC 5 on Owin/Katana or self host. It needs IIS.

But ASP.Net Core completely runs on Owin and selfHost.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, I think it's because asp.net mvc5 tight binding with system.web assymby, which is an integral part .net framework